# How to check where is db structure of the search bar in magento version 2.1.1?

Tags: magento-2.1

The search of my website is a mess which made in **Magento version 2.1.1**.When search any product it gives not the actual product. I have installed plugins, but it also not affect it. Anyone has a better suggestion for it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try simply reindexing from CLI?

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

From Magento root path.

Comment: Yes, i did it.but it only resolve my sid issue.

Comment: What do ypu mean by "sid issue"?